Why do Kontsevich and Rosenberg use algebra epimorphisms rather than surjections?
In the article Noncommutative spaces Kontsevich and Rosenberg make the following definition:
2.6. The Q-category of infinitesimal algebra epimorphisms. Let $A$ be the
category $Alg_k$ of associative unital $k$-algebras, and let $\bar{A}$ be the full subcategory of the category $Alg_k^2$ of $k$-algebra morphisms whose objects are epimorphisms with a nilpotent kernel.
In my previous experience with infinitesimal extensions such as Exalcomm one considers surjective homomorphisms rather than epimorphisms. For what technical reason do Kontsevich and Rosenberg use epimorphisms instead of surjections?

I have not really qualified to comment on your question, but could it just be that they are using "epimorphism" to mean "surjective homomorphism" rather than epimorphism in the categorical sense? I have definitely seen this (unfortunate) convention in other texts.

In some categories, there exist epimorphisms that are not surjective.  I do not know about this category, however.

You want to mimic the idea of including a scheme X into a scheme Y where Y is an infinitesimal deformation of X, i.e. you want this to be a monomorphism of schemes. In the commutative case, this corresponds to being an epimorphism of commutative algebras, which is not necessarily the same as being a surjection.

Note that this is different than the case of Exalcomm because you're doing arbitrary deformations, not a square zero extension by a module. The latter is much more "controlled."

@JonathanBeardsley what is your definition of infinitesimal deformation? The first thing that comes to mind for me is a finite order thickening as described in the stacks project here https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/04EW. But they require closed subscheme, i.e., surjection of rings.

@NickMertes I don't know off the top of my head, and don't expect to have the energy to work through the details any time soon (hence the comment as opposed to an answer; low commitment lol). I also can't know what Kontsevich and Rosenberg were specifically thinking, obviously. But I will point out that being a monomorphism of schemes is strictly more general than being a closed subscheme. So maybe they wanted to get the most general sort of object they could.
